# Origin of "On your own head be it"?

Tags: phrase-origin

The phrase “on your own head be it” is common-ish and has the well-attested meaning of roughly “I think this is a really terrible idea but you’re the one who will suffer the consequences so do what you like.”

But I cannot find any information as to the phrase’s origins. I’d kind of suspected Shakespeare or maybe the King James Bible, but neither seems to include it that I could find. Various online dictionaries list the phrase, but offer no origin. So I’m wondering if anyone here knows, or can dig it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earliest quote in the OED for this expression is from 1743:

> When they promise it [sc. protection], they put their hands up to their turbants, as much as to say, Be it on their heads.
>   <sub>[A description of the East, and some other countries](https://books.google.com/books?id=0GZUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA182&dq="Be+it+on+their+heads")</sub>

However, I think I found an earlier example from 1711:

> If you dissemble, be it on your head
>   <sub>[The maids tragedy](https://books.google.com/books?id=DyNEAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA208&dq="Be+it+on+your+head")</sub>

---

The expression "on your head", however, is much older than the longer expression (and apparently comes from the Latin expression *in caput eius* meaning "onto his/her head"). Since Old English, it was used in the sense "Of a misfortune, curse, blessing, etc.: directed towards a person; so as to affect a person; on a person." (OED):

> Gehweorfe his sar on his heafod [L. *in caput eius*], and on his brægn astige his unriht.
>   <sub>[King Alfred's Psalms](https://books.google.com/books?id=z09KAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq="Gehweorfe+his+sar+on+his+heafod") (Psalm 7:16)</sub>

In the sense "So as to be the responsibility of a person; weighing on a person", the earliest attestation the OED has is from a1425:

> The blood of hym schal be on his heed [a1382 E.V. into his hed, L. in caput eius], that goith out at the dore of thin hows.
>   <sub>[John Wycliffe Bible](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Wycliffe/6/2)</sub>

Comment: Nice! It would be nice to get a little bit more details about those works (say, author) into the answer itself, though, rather than relying on external sites.

Answer (score 2):

It appears it is from the Bible:

“*[On your own
head be it](https://www.kjvsayings.com/phrase/on-your-own-head-be-it)*”

> Source: This phrase has its origins in Psalm 7:16 and Acts 18:6 of the King James Version of the Bible.

Meaning: the ultimate responsibility is yours

and according to the AHD it dates back to the 14th century:

***[On one's head](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/on-one-s-head)***:

> Also, on one's own head . As one's responsibility or fault, as in If the police catch you speeding it's on your own head . ***This idiom, dating from the 1300s, conjures up the image of blame or guilt falling on someone's head.***

Answer (score 1):

Ezekiel 33 verses 1-4 but especially verse 4 (KJV)... Then whosoever heareth the sound of the trumpet, and taketh not warning; if the sword come, and take him away, his blood shall be upon his own head. The preceding verses talk about a watchman being appointed by the people to watch for the approach of the enemy. he was to blow the trumpet to warn the people if the enemy was approaching - but verse 4 says they (the people) bear the (fatal)consequences alone if they fail to heed the warning. Yes psalm 7:16 has been mentioned and also Acts 18:6 but I think Ezekiel 33:4 is the best example of the phrase 'on your own head be it'.